# I'm getting an EOF error while running my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

I'm getting an EOF error while running my code.I think I messed up with input(). Don't know how to solve it. I tried different ways.

```py
print("Enter a number")

number = int(input())

while(number>4):
    
  print("Number is greater than 4")
    
  number = int(input())
   
  if (number ==9):
        break
  if number ==8:
        continue
   
  print("loop ended")
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please provide more information.

Comment: I'm just creating a while loop which takes input

Comment: How are you running this?  If you did, for example, `echo 3 | python xxx.py`, you would see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Code doesn´t catch invalid literals.

```py
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if number == 9:
        break
    elif number == 8:
        print(number)
    elif number > 4:
        print("Number is greater than 4")
    else:
        print("Number is less equal than 4")

print("loop ended")
```